Angular: Replace placeholder with input box inside a html table at runtime
I get a partial html from an API, then I need to insert input boxes by replacing a placeholder. Think of this as creating a fill in the blanks kind of a form at runtime.
I have a solution where I split the input string into fragments using the placeholder, "~~~~~~" in this case and run a ngFor in the HTML template, set the innerHTML using the fragments and insert the input boxes.
This works normally but breaks when a html table is provided as the input string.
The input string from API:
Note: This is just an example and there will be more than one input boxes in multiple rows.
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>~~~~~~</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Angular HTML template:
<form [formGroup]="blanksForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div>
    <span *ngFor="let fragment of sentenceFragments; let i = index">
        <span [innerHtml]="fragment"></span>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="i < sentenceFragments.length - 1" appearance="outline">
            <input matInput formControlName="blank{{ i + 1 }}" />
        </mat-form-field>
    </span>
  </div>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

TS file:
processHtmlString() {
    const parts = this.htmlString.split('~~~~~~'); // Split by the placeholder
    for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        const safeFragment = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(parts[i]);
        this.sentenceFragments.push(safeFragment);

        // Create a form control for each blank except the last one
        if (i < parts.length - 1) {
            this.blanksForm.addControl(`blank${i + 1}`, new FormControl(''));
        }
    }
}

Expected output:

I think I know the problem, the table HTML structure breaks when I set the innerHTML on the span tag.
But I can't seem to figure out a good solution to solve this problem.
I have created a minimalistic code to demonstrate the problem.
Stackblitz
Any idea's are much appreciated.

Unfortunately you probably need to set the whole html as innerHtml and then manually create mat-form-field components

I would suggest 2 options:

Get the values from the table and construct an array of values where you can map later as in an Angular project.
Check the links:
getElementByTagName,    get table cells

Rconstruct the HTML element



Delete the useless data
 <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">----</td>

Detect the row for the age (number) and use it as input.
That would be a super job to be done and not worth it. Assuming you have a normal table not with a single person.


Extra suggestion. Ask for a better API.

Thanks for the suggestion, but the input maybe a table or normal HTML you get from wysiwyg editor, I cannot run logic specific to html tags.
